# How can I avoid keyPressed method to make my draw permenant in Processing 3?

Tags: java, processing

I'm trying to create a HangMan game since it's an assignment. In the game() method, I want to call some methods from dead class if player's input is wrong. These methods creates HangMan. When I input a wrong letter and press Enter (increasing numWrong) related method is called but only flashes and disappears. I know it because of keyPressed method but how can I draw HangMan on screen and make it permanent till end of the game.

```
String[] words = {"dictionary","game","player","result"};
char[] strChar, guessed, wrong;

float x, y;
String str, display, display2, typing="", guess="", win = "", lost = "", wrongAnswers;
int rnd, c, numRight=0, winner=0, numWrong=0;

void setup() {
  size(800, 800); 
  surface.setLocation(960, 0);

  x = width;
  y = height;

  rnd = words.length-1;  
  str = words[(int)random(rnd)].toUpperCase();
  strChar = new char[str.length()];

  winner = str.length();

  guessed = new char[str.length()];

  for (int c=0; c<str.length(); c++) {
    strChar[c] = str.charAt(c);
    guessed[c] = '_';
  }

  wrong = new char[6];
  for (int i=0; i<wrong.length; i++) {
    wrong[i] = '*';
  }
}

void draw() {
  background(10);

  display = "Write a letter then press ENTER.";
  display2 = " ";
  wrongAnswers = "Incorrect Guesses: ";  

  for (int d=0; d<guessed.length; d++) {
    display2 = display2 +" "+guessed[d];
  }

  for (int i=0; i<wrong.length; i++) {
    wrongAnswers = wrongAnswers+" "+wrong[i];
  }

  fill(255);
  textSize(40);
  text(display2, 40, 750);

  textSize(20);
  text(display, 450, 380);

  textSize(250);
  text(typing.toUpperCase(), 450, 245);

  strokeWeight(1);
  d.gallows(); 

  fill(55, 200, 155);
  textSize(50);
  text(win, 110, 680);
  textSize(50);
  text(lost, 110, 680);
  textSize(20);
  text(wrongAnswers, 410, 690);

  //origins
  stroke(100, 150, 200);
  strokeWeight(2);
  line(0, 700, x, 700);//seperate line
  line(x/2, 0, x/2, 700);//vertical line
  line(x/2, y/2, x, y/2);//horizontal line

  fill(255);
  textSize(35);
  text(str, 90, 560);
}

void game(String guess) {
  guess = guess.toUpperCase();
  char myGuess = guess.charAt(0);
  boolean guessedRight = false;

  for (int m=0; m<str.length(); m++) {    
    if (myGuess==str.charAt(m)) {      
      if (exist(display2, myGuess)) {
        guessed[m] = myGuess;
        numRight++;
        guessedRight = true;
      } 
      if (numRight == winner) {        
        win = "YOU WIN!!";
      }
    }
  }
  if (guessedRight == false) {
    wrong[numWrong] = myGuess;
    numWrong++;

    noStroke();
    fill(255);

    if (numWrong==1) {
      d.headAndRope();
    } 
    if (numWrong==2) { 
      d.body(); 
      d.headAndRope();
    }  
    if (numWrong==3) { 
      d.leftArm(); 
      d.body(); 
      d.headAndRope();
    }  
    if (numWrong==4) {
      d.rightArm(); 
      d.leftArm(); 
      d.body(); 
      d.headAndRope();
    }  
    if (numWrong==5) {
      d.leftLeg(); 
      d.rightArm(); 
      d.leftArm(); 
      d.body(); 
      d.headAndRope();
    }  
    if (numWrong==6) {
      d.rightLeg(); 
      d.leftLeg(); 
      d.rightArm(); 
      d.leftArm(); 
      d.body(); 
      d.headAndRope();
    }

    if (numWrong == wrong.length) {
      lost = "YOU LOSE!!";
    }
  }
}

void keyPressed() {
  if (key == '\n') {
    game(typing);
    typing = "";    
  } else {    
    typing+=key;
  }
}

boolean exist(String sng, char cha) {
  for (int i=0; i<sng.length(); i++) {
    if (sng.charAt(i)==cha) {
      return false;
    }
  }  
  return true;
}

//DEAD CLASS

class Dead {

  void gallows() {   

    stroke(0);

    //base
    fill(127);
    rect(40, 600, 340, 30);

    //left vertical rect
    fill(200, 100, 50);
    rect(60, 50, 10, 550);

    //right vertical rect
    fill(100, 50, 25);
    rect(70, 50, 10, 550);

    //top horizontal rect
    fill(200, 100, 50);
    rect(60, 40, 300, 10);

    //bottom horizontal rect
    fill(100, 50, 25);
    rect(70, 50, 290, 10);

    //diagonal bottom rect
    fill(100, 50, 25);
    beginShape();
    vertex(80, 250);
    vertex(80, 265);
    vertex(265, 60);
    vertex(250, 60);
    endShape(CLOSE);

    //diagonal top rect
    fill(200, 100, 50);
    beginShape();
    vertex(70, 245);
    vertex(70, 260);
    vertex(260, 50);
    vertex(245, 50);
    endShape(CLOSE);
  }

  void headAndRope() {
    //rope
    fill(255);
    rect(300, 40, 2, 95);
    //head
    fill(255);
    ellipse(301, 155, 50, 75);
  }
  void body() {
    //body
    stroke(255);
    strokeWeight(3);
    line(301, 193, 301, 375);
  }
  void leftArm() {
    //left arm
    stroke(255);
    strokeWeight(2);
    line(301, 223, 251, 300);
  }
  void rightArm() {
    //right arm
    stroke(255);
    strokeWeight(2);
    line(301, 223, 351, 300);
  }
  void leftLeg() {
    //left leg
    stroke(255);
    strokeWeight(2);
    line(301, 375, 251, 450);
  }
  void rightLeg() {
    //right leg
    stroke(255);
    strokeWeight(2);
    line(301, 375, 351, 450);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Processing the `draw` function gets called every frame, completely redrawing everything on the screen. So if you want the hangman to always appear on the screen, you'll need to draw it in the `draw` function (or in a function that gets called from `draw`).

If you restructure your code slightly everything should work:

```
void draw() {
  // draw UI and input prompt based on `numRight` value
  // NEW: draw the current state of the hangman based on `numWrong` value
}

void game(String guess) {
  // update the game state (`numRight` and `numWrong` variables)
  // based on `guess` input
  // NEW: since this is only called momentarily, don't do any drawing here
}

void keyPressed() {
  // receive key input and pass it to `game`
}
```

Since `game` only gets called momentarily when the user enters a guess, you don't want to be doing any drawing in there. It will get overwritten in the next `draw` cycle. You can still update the game state in `game`, but the drawing representation of that game state should happen from `draw` to ensure it gets drawn every time the screen updates.